# $location changes does not propagate

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller videoCtrl as follow:

```
app.controller('videoCtrl',function($scope,$location){

$scope.location = $location.path();
```

});
and in html i have:

```
   <div style="position: relative" ng-controller="videoCtrl">
        <p>{{location}}</p>
</div>
```

When i start with the path named '/parts' its shows correctly parts. But when i change the path to '/established' the change will not take effect and it remains '/parts'. Is it normal?

Comment: `$location.path()` returns a string value representing the value **at the time the function is called**.  even if the value changes, the function isn't called again, so `$scope.location` will never change.  If you want to update your values whenever the location changes, you need to create a watcher for the `$locationChangeStart` or `$locationChangeSuccess` events.

Comment: I dont know having a watcher is better or the solution proposed by John Galagher. And i wish I would have the proper code for watcher.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be addressed in a few different ways.

The root of the issue is that `$location.path()` is a function which returns a string representing the **value at the time the function is called**.  Unfortunately, this function is only called *once*, when the controller is first initialized.  This would *seem to indicate* that you are using the same controller for more than one path.

Possible ways to address the issue, in order of efficiency, would include:

1. Use a unique controller for each path (this can be done automatically with a router like angular ngRoute or the 3rd party ui-router).  When the controller for that path is initialized, the function will run, and the value will be the correct, current path.
2. Use a watcher like

   ```
   $rootScope.on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
     $scope.location = $location.path();
   });
   ```

   This watcher will be fired any time the location is successfully changed, and will update your value appropriately.
3. Use a function bound in the HTML like

   ```
   <p>{{getLocation()}}</p>

   $scope.getLocation = $location.path;
   ```

   This will *implicitly* create a watcher which will fire the `$location.path()` function **every `$digest` cycle**.

Comment: Ah, it does look like a watched *would* be more efficient. Thanks for the tip and here's your upvote!

Answer (score 1):

The location that you are setting in your controller is only getting set once. If you would like angular to continually watch the location, you'll need to have it added to your html via a function as follows.

Instead of having your html look like:

```
<p>{{location}}</p>
```

with the following js in your controller:

```
$scope.location = $location.path();
```

try html:

```
<p>{{getLocation()}}</p>
```

and js:

```
$scope.getLocation = $location.path;
```

---

By evaluating a function inside the expression injected into your html, AngularJS will set up some stuff that will watch the value returned by $scope.getLocation() and update your DOM respectively on changes.